# Extracting the text which is not in between tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm practicing BeautifulSoup by scraping [imdb.com](https://imdb.com) and for a given actor I would like to

1. get the list of all films they starred in as an actor;
2. filter our all films that are not full-length features, i.e. TV series, short films, short documentaries, etc.

So far for all films I can get something like the following soup:

```
<div class="filmo-row even" id="actor-tt14677742">
    <span class="year_column">2021</span>
    <b><a href="/title/tt14677742/">Welcome Back Future</a></b>
     (Short)
    <br/>
     Leo
</div>
```

As we can see, this film should be filtered out, because it's a short one. We can also see that the info about that `(Short)` is not wrapped in any tags.
Thus, My question:
**How can I get this information from the soup, how can I look for some info after `</b>` if there is any at all?**

Comment: Can you maybe turn the soup back into a string and then do a fulltext search to look for `"(Short)"` in it?

Comment: what happens if you try to get the `div`'s `.text`? so sth like: `soup.find('div', class_='filmo-row even').text`

Comment: @Matiiss in that way result will be all text, but using [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68550605/12446721) OP will only got text from outside that div.

Comment: @ok, but using my idea it would as simple as `if "(Short)" in soup.find('div', class_='filmo-row even').text:`, there won't be really any need for clearing up the list items (the only issue if there is a movie with that exact name and it is not a short)

Comment: I don't think that is wrong. :)

Comment: what's the expected output ? why there's multiple questions in one ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη where did you found multiple questions? Cuz I don't think there is multiple questions!

Comment: @Xitiz point 1 and 2 is enough to be multiple question, and the rest of POST.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

HTML="""<div class="filmo-row even" id="actor-tt14677742">
    <span class="year_column">2021</span>
    <b><a href="/title/tt14677742/">Welcome Back Future</a></b>
     (Short)
    <br/>
     Leo
</div>
"""

soup=bs(HTML,"lxml")

print(soup.find("div").find_all(text=True,recursive=False))
# ['\n', '\n', '\n     (Short)\n    ', '\n     Leo\n']

# If you use html5lib as parse then answer is a bit different:
soup=bs(HTML,"html5lib")
print(soup.find("div").find_all(text=True,recursive=False))
# ['\n    ', '\n    ', '\n     (Short)\n    ', '\n     Leo\n']

# If you want all of the text from div then try this:
print(soup.find("div").find_all(text=True,recursive=True))
# ['\n', '2021', '\n', 'Welcome Back Future', '\n     (Short)\n    ', '\n     Leo\n']
# Or simply use
print(soup.find("div").text)
"""
2021
Welcome Back Future
     (Short)

     Leo

"""
```

I think you can clean it now, and I believe *get the list of all films they starred in as an actor;* mean you also need `Leo`.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, I'm not sure what you are looking for it. But based on comments and the other answer.

Below should achieve your goal.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''<div class="filmo-row even" id="actor-tt14677742">
    <span class="year_column">2021</span>
    <b><a href="/title/tt14677742/">Welcome Back Future</a></b>
     (Short)
    <br/>
     Leo
</div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(list(soup.select_one('.filmo-row').stripped_strings))
```

Output:

```
['2021', 'Welcome Back Future', '(Short)', 'Leo']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `bs4`, but somehow looking for `next_sibling` and that solved my problem.

So I do this:

```
category = movie_soup.find_all('b')[0].next_sibling
if 'TV' in category or 'Short' in category or 'Series' in category or 'Video' in category or 'Documentary' in category:
    return None, None
```

and if I find the movie that I don't need because it falls into one of the categories I don't need, I return None, None. I know it's not the best piece of code style-wise, but it works for me.

Comment: I believe, if you're using 0th element`[0]` then you don't need to do `.find_all()`, you can use `.find()` and doing `movie_soup.find("b").next_sibling.strip()` is good! `.strip()` will remove unnecessary white space.